# how to analysis the time-series data for pattern recognition

Tags: algorithm, statistics, time-series

I want to analyze time-series for pattern recognition (sudden spikes ,ups and downs etc) , what my concern is , we have many algorithm for that

ARIMA and other methods are useful when we have a data like `(timestamp , int_vlaues)`

i do have have data which have time-stamp in proper format but next all columns don't have `int_value` in it, but all are useful for analysis

does PCA(Principal Component Analysis) help me ?

should i go for neural-network?

or any other your suggestions will appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: NN would be better !! as per my opinion